# adding background to JFrame in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I want to set an image on my background in JFrame but I can't.
this the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("pic.png");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JLabel background = new JLabel();
    background.setIcon(image);
    background.setBounds(0 , 0 , 200 , 200);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1080, 720);
    frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setContentPane(background);
    }
}
```

I tried another examples but didn't works!

Comment: please keep your tags focused - this is unrelated to javafx

Comment: You should call `frame.setContentPane(background)` before `frame.setVisible(true)`. However I did close as a duplicate with another answer showing a similar technique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are currently doing is to simply create a new `JLabel` object (i.e `background`) to which you add an image object.

This will not achieve what you want to accomplish. Unfortunately, there is no out of the box way to add an image as a background to a `JFrame` but you can easily try this:

```
public class BackGroundFrame extends JFrame {

    public BackGroundFrame() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\tmp\\test.jpg"));
        add(background);
        background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        background.add(new JLabel("My Label"));
        background.add(new JButton("My button"));
        revalidate();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new BackGroundFrame();
    }

}
```

This will effectively create a new frame having a label that has a background, to which you can then add new elements.

Using this should accomplish what you are trying to achieve.